# Azure Log Analytics Agent(Microsoft Monitoring Agent) installation error (Error:Failed to connect, exception : System.Net.WebException: )

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am getting error while installing Microsoft Monitoring Agent.

[Installation Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6c8Q.png)

I look at the Monitoring agent log file available in %temp% file and it shows below Error.

```
    Error:  Failed to connect, exception : System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.MOMv3.Setup.MOMv3ManagedCAs.ValidateOpInsightsConnection(Session session)
```

I check communication and firewall all are ok but getting same error. I have referrer official document [troubleshoot issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-windows-troubleshoot#log-analytics-troubleshooting-tool) as well but didn't help much on this. Same Agent we are able to install on other systems and working fine. So our Workspace key and ID is working fine.

please help here to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue can be resolved by set up correct registry entry. If Hardening is applied and lower version of TLS is disabled then above issue will occur.

This is basically TLS handshake issue between target system and Azure Log Analytics.

To resolve, we have to Setup below Registry policy.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```